# VBA Excel inputbox run time error 13 type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, input, vb6

I have a macro which is working well. But the issue I have is with the InputBox. The macro is running into errors when the user **presses CANCEL or X** out of the InputBox.  **The user can input up to 15 values to search and enters 0 for the search to begin.** I want to make it more robust so i wont run into these errors. Please help.

```
Sub FindValues()    
    Dim LSearchRow As Integer
    Dim rw As Integer, cl As Range, LSearchValue As Long, LCopyToRow As Integer
    Dim iHowMany As Integer
    Dim aSearch(15) As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    ' clear the sheets before it runs so to accurate number of funds opend.

    Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("tier 2").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("tier 3").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("tier 4").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("tier 5").Cells.ClearContents

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    FixC
    Sheet2.Cells.Clear
    Sheet1.Select
    iHowMany = 0
    LSearchValue = 99

    'this for the end user to input the required A/C to be searched

    Do While LSearchValue <> 0
        LSearchValue = InputBox("Please enter a value to search for. Enter a zero to indicate finished" & _
    "entry.", "Enter Search value")
        If LSearchValue <> 0 Then
            iHowMany = iHowMany + 1
            If iHowMany > 15 Then
                MsgBox "You are limited to 15 search numbers.", vbOKOnly, "Limit reached"
                iHowMany = 15
                Exit Do
            End If
            aSearch(iHowMany) = LSearchValue
        End If
    Loop

    If iHowMany = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No selections entered.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "No Search data"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    LCopyToRow = 2

    For rw = 1 To 1555
        For Each cl In Range("D" & rw & ":M" & rw)
        '------------------------------------------------
            For i = 1 To iHowMany
                Debug.Print cl.Row & vbTab & cl.Column
                LSearchValue = aSearch(i)
                If cl = LSearchValue Then
                    cl.EntireRow.Copy
                    'Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2")
                    '.Rows(LCopyToRow & ":" & LCopyToRow)
                    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                    Rows(LCopyToRow & ":" & LCopyToRow).Select
                    'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
                       xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                    'Move counter to next row
                    LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
                    'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                End If
            Next i
            'LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
        Next cl
    Next rw
    'Position on cell A3
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet2.Select
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a string variable `Dim LSearchString as String` and assign it the return value of your InputBox: `LSearchString = InputBox(...)`. Now you can check the input for being numeric: `If IsNumeric(LSearchString)` and handle wrong input. If successful you can proceed to convert it to an integer: `LSearchValue = CInt(LSearchString)`. You have to know that `CInt()` always returns 0 if the argument is not a number.

The following code snippet is an modified extract from your code.
Wrong inputs just are ignored.

**UPDATE**

```
Dim LSearchValue As Integer
Dim LSearchString As String

'..........

LSearchValue = 99

Do While True
    LSearchString = InputBox( _
           "Please enter a value to search for. " & _
           "Enter a zero to indicate finished entry", _
           "Enter Search value")

    If IsNumeric(LSearchString) Then
        LSearchValue = CInt(LSearchString)
        If LSearchValue = 0 Then Exit Do

        iHowMany = iHowMany + 1
        If iHowMany > 15 Then
            MsgBox "You are limited to 15 search numbers.", vbOKOnly, "Limit reached"
            iHowMany = 15
            Exit Do
        End If
        aSearch(iHowMany) = LSearchValue
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: hi thanks for this . can you put it into code please i will really appericate it

Comment: can you put this in script? been trying it and its not working for me

Comment: @kay: It could be something like that (see update). You'd had to replace the part of your code with the inputbox.

Comment: Thats looking good , just came across an overflow issue . But the question i asked is  working well, thanks . Will keep you posted about the overflow issue , working on that now.  Great community

Comment: I fixed the overflow issue , just changed the variable from integer to long. which in turn had to be Clng. Thanks alot for this real help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle a **Cancel,** use an intermediate *Variant*

```
Sub dural()
    Dim v As Variant, LSearchValue As Long
    v = InputBox("Please enter a value to search for. Enter a zero to indicate finished" & "entry.", "Enter Search value")
    If v = "" Then
        MsgBox "I guess you don't want to search"
    Else
        LSearchValue = CLng(v)
        MsgBox "I will search for " & LSearchValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Pefect that works well on my cancel button.. great. If a user X's out i am running into the same error.

Comment: this code works i have been trying to make exit when then user presses the cancel button, instead of the input box popping up again